# Feign - define param value for each methods

Tags: feign

I need to write a client with multiple methods that require the apiKey as query string param. Is it possible to allow the client's user to pass the api key only to the method `withApiKey`, so I can avoid to request the apiKey as first parameter of each method?

```
public interface Client {
    @RequestLine("GET /search/search?key={apiKey}&query={query}&limit={limit}&offset={offset}")
    SearchResponse search(@Param("apiKey") String apiKey, @Param("query") String query, @Param("limit") Integer limit, @Param("offset") Integer offset);

    @RequestLine("GET /product/attributes?key={apiKey}&products={products}")
    List<Product> getProduct(@Param("apiKey") String apiKey, @Param("products") String products);

    public class Builder {
        private String basePath;
        private String apiKey;

        public Client build() {
            return Feign.builder()
                    .encoder(new JacksonEncoder())
                    .decoder(new JacksonDecoder())
                    .client(new ApacheHttpClient())
                    .logger(new Slf4jLogger())
                    .logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL)
                    .target(Client.class, basePath);

        }

        public Builder withBasePath(String basePath) {
            this.basePath = basePath;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withApiKey(String apiKey) {
            this.apiKey = apiKey;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the setup request-interceptors might work: https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#request-interceptors

Hopefully the example below will help.

You can swap the builder out for just the interface annotation and then move the configuration to a configuration class, if you are using spring it could be like:

```
@FeignClient(
    name = "ClerkClient",
    url = "${clery-client.url}", // instead of the withBasePath method 
    configuration = {ClerkClientConfiguration.class}
)
public interface Client {
```

Then the ClerkClientConfiguration class can define the required config beans including a ClerkClientInterceptor

```
public class ClerkClientConfiguration {

@Bean
public RequestInterceptor clerkClientInterceptor() {
    return new ClerkClientInterceptor();
}
```

Then the interceptor can have a value picked up from the config and added to the queries (or header etc)

```
    public class ClerkClientInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    
    @Value("${clerk-client.key}")
    private String apiKey

    @Override public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
       requestTemplate.query( "key", apiKey); 
    }
```